# organize and display logs by modules on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express

I am wondering if there is a way to organize and (un)activate logs on NodeJS.

Writing relevant logs takes time and comment/uncomment it is dirty and make us loose time.

I am looking for something close than the [logs module](https://github.com/visionmedia/log.js), except i would like to be able to create custom kinds of logs (more than 'debug', 'info'... but according to some parts of the projects i work on, like 'authentication', 'game-engine'...) and say to node (express) which kind of logs i want to be displayed when i run it.

Do you know a module or an approach to work this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [node-bunyan](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan) and [winston](https://github.com/flatiron/winston) for logging.

You can use `process.env.NODE_ENV` environment variable to change log level & configuration.